# How to login into a web with curl?

Tags: curl, authentication

```
Testing site: http://testing-ground.scraping.pro/login
Username: admin
Password: 12345
```

Curl help

```
-u, --user <user:password> Server user and password
```

Here is the web form

```
wolf@linux:~$ curl http://testing-ground.scraping.pro/login 2>/dev/null | sed -n '/<form/,/form>/'p
    <form action="login?mode=login" method="POST">
        <label for="usr">User name:</label>
        <input id="usr" name="usr" type="text" placeholder="enter 'admin' here">
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input id="pwd" name="pwd" type="text" placeholder="enter '12345' here">
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
wolf@linux:~$
```

Curl without credentials

```
wolf@linux:~$ curl http://testing-ground.scraping.pro/login?mode=login 2>/dev/null | egrep 'DENIED|WELCOME'
        <li>If you see <span class="success">WELCOME :)</span> then the user credentials were sent, the cookie was passed and HTTP redirect was processed</li>
        <li>If you see <span class="error">ACCESS DENIED!</span> then either you entered wrong credentials or they were not sent to the server properly</li>
<h3 class='error'>ACCESS DENIED!</h3><a href='login'>&lt;&lt;&nbsp;GO BACK</a></div>
wolf@linux:~$
```

However, curl with credentials `-u admin:12345` also shows the same page ...

```
wolf@linux:~$ curl http://testing-ground.scraping.pro/login?mode=login -u admin:12345 2>/dev/null | egrep 'DENIED|WELCOME'
        <li>If you see <span class="success">WELCOME :)</span> then the user credentials were sent, the cookie was passed and HTTP redirect was processed</li>
        <li>If you see <span class="error">ACCESS DENIED!</span> then either you entered wrong credentials or they were not sent to the server properly</li>
<h3 class='error'>ACCESS DENIED!</h3><a href='login'>&lt;&lt;&nbsp;GO BACK</a></div>
wolf@linux:~$
```

What is the right way to use curl in this case?

Comment: Several approaches can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594880/using-curl-with-a-username-and-password). I would try `curl http://admin:12345@testing-ground.scraping.pro/`

Comment: Thanks @eblock. This seems to work as well, however I did not see any `success` message with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
curl -s -L --cookie-jar cookies.txt -d 'usr=admin&pwd=12345' http://testing-ground.scraping.pro/login?mode=login | grep -E 'DENIED|WELCOME'
```

Output:

```
        <li>If you see <span class="success">WELCOME :)</span> then the user credentials were sent, the cookie was passed and HTTP redirect was processed</li>
        <li>If you see <span class="error">ACCESS DENIED!</span> then either you entered wrong credentials or they were not sent to the server properly</li>
<h3 class='success'>WELCOME :)</h3><a href='login'>&lt;&lt;&nbsp;GO BACK</a></div>
```

- `-s` quiet mode without progress bar. Output is sent to stdout.
- `-L` follow the 302 redirect
- `--cookie-jar cookies.txt` use cookies and write cookies to file `cookies.txt`
- `-d 'usr=admin&pwd=12345'` POST data `usr=admin` and `pwd=12345`

Comment: Thanks for the tips. `-s` or `--silent` is cool. `2>/dev/null` is not required anymore with `-s